# Force NTP step whenever the Internet comes up

Tags: ntp, ntpd, chrony

Assume there is a PC with dead CMOS battery and unreliable Internet connection.

As far as I understand, both `chrony` and `ntpd` try to correct huge time differences (years) *once* – upon startup, – but then switch to slewing during normal system run, which will panic and bail out if the needed time correction is more than 1000 s. Sometimes the Internet connection is absent at boot time but comes up later; but my system is forever stuck in the past.

Right now I solve this by manually calling

```
chronyc burst 4/4
```

on OpenSuSE (chrony) or

```
service ntp stop
ntpd -gq
service ntp start
```

on antiX (ntpd).

I wonder if there is some way to attach this to some hook that would fire once whenever the Internet comes up.

Answer (score 0):

So you already know how to step your NTP daemons, but only need the place to hook the commands.

SuSE seems to use NetworkManager by default, so `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/` would be the place for scripts to run whenever network configuration changes... and there should already be a `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/20-chrony` which you can use as an example. For more details, see `man NetworkManager-dispatcher`.

AntiX is a Debian derivative. It appears to use `connman` by default, and unfortunately it does not seem to provide an easy way to add custom scripts to network available/unavailable events. However, it seems to provide a `connman-wait-online.service`, which is associated with the `network-online.target`. If you ensure your regular `ntpd` service start-up is configured to happen only after the systemd target `network-online.target` is reached, and that it allows `ntpd` to step on first startup, I think that might satisfy your requirement.

Comment: I see... I tried to approach this problem from the daemon side, thinking that thery should have some option to keep trying to sync instead of giving up if the first try (on boot) fails. Apparently not. Well, thanks for your answer, I'll give it a shot.